# All Pairs Shortest Paths Udaya Kumar Redd Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Using the algorithm on Page 4 of the following paper, 
I am attempting to compute an all pairs shortest paths matrix.

http://www.waset.org/journals/ijcms/v3/v3-5-43.pdf

I am confused by lines 7 and 8 (of the algorithm) and subsequently, 11 and 12, 
because assigning s1 the value of j and using both these
it the comparison on line 8 seems ambiguous to me. I am 
wondering if perhaps I am reading the indentation wrong.
I am new to algorithms so please be patient with me.

```
    while(flag != false){
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            aMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            bMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for(int j=0; j<n;j++){
                // Line 7 of the algorithm
                if((distanceMatrix[i][j] < aMin) && (j != i) && (BR[i][j] == false)){
                    aMin = distanceMatrix[i][j];
                    BR[i][j] = true;
                    a[i] = j;
                    int s1 = j; // End of line 7
                    // Line 8 of the algorithm
                    if(distanceMatrix[i][j] < distanceMatrix[i][s1])
                        BR[i][s1] = false; // End of line 8
                }

            }

            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                // Line 11 of the algorithm
                if((distanceMatrix[i][j] < bMin) && (j != i) && (j != a[i]) && (BR[i][j] == false)){
                    bMin = distanceMatrix[i][j];
                    BR[i][j] = true;
                    b[i] = j;
                    int s2 = j; // end of line 11

                    // Line 12 of the algorithm
                    if(distanceMatrix[i][j] < distanceMatrix[i][s2])
                        BR[i][s2] = false; // end of line 12
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i <n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                int t1 = distanceMatrix[i][a[i]] + distanceMatrix[a[i]][j];
                int t2 = distanceMatrix[i][b[i]] + distanceMatrix[b[i]][j];
                distanceMatrix[i][j] = Math.min(distanceMatrix[i][j], Math.min(t1,t2));
                distanceMatrix[j][i] = distanceMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        flag = true;
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            // Line 19 of the algorithm
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                temp[i][j] = distanceMatrix[i][j]; // end of line 19
                // Line 20 of the algorithm
                if (distanceMatrix[i][j] == temp[i][j])
                    flag  = false; // end of line 20
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, I understand by looking at line 19 and 20 in the algorithm, it will get stuck in a loop because flag will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
4) for i ← 1 to n do amin← ∞ ; bmin ← ∞
5)   for j ← 1 to n do
6)     if D[i, j] < amin and j = i and BR[i, j] = 0 then
7)       amin ← D[i, j] ; BR[i, j] ← 1 ; a[i] ← j ; s1 ← j
8)     if D[i, j] < D[i, s1] then BR[i, s1] ← 0
```

So as you can see, `s1` might not always be `j`: it will always be `<= j` however.

So the second `if` is not inside the first. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense, because `s1 == j` always and you cannot have `D[i, j] < D[i, j]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If this is the case, then I would guess s1 would need to be initialised prior to being used in the if statement, however the paper does not state what this value actually is or what it should be. Do you happen to have an understanding on this? s1 = i, maybe?

Comment: @user1491153 - I would initialize it with `-1` and check if `s1 != -1` before triggering the second `if`.